# Implementing pre-roll video iAds

Tags: ios, xcode, iad

In October 2014 Apple announced pre-roll video as a new ad format for iAd

https://developer.apple.com/iad/resources/Implementing-iAd-in-Your-iOS-Apps.PDF

However, there is no official documentation on implementing them. Is this format available yet and if so how can they be implemented?

Comment: did you manage to find an answer?

Comment: Techotopia has got you covered.. check out this link, http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Integrating_iAds_into_an_iOS_7_App,  and come back to me if it doesn't help any, alright? - Dan

Answer (score 0):

Check my example for a working implementation of iAd's prerolled video ads:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@import iAd;
@import MediaPlayer;

@interface ViewController () {
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Preload ad
    [MPMoviePlayerController preparePrerollAds];

    // Create our MPMoviePlayerController
    moviePlayer =[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]init];
    [moviePlayer.view setFrame: self.view.bounds];
    [moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
}

-(IBAction)playButton:(id)sender {
    // Add MPMoviePlayerController to our view
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];

    // Path of movie you want to play
    NSString *moviePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"someVideo" ofType:@"MOV"];

    // Set the contents of our MPMoviePlayerController to our path
    [moviePlayer setContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath]];

    // Prepare our movie for playback
    [moviePlayer prepareToPlay];

    // Play our movie with a prerolled ad
    [moviePlayer playPrerollAdWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"%@",error);
        }
        [moviePlayer play];
    }];
}
```