# Is iAd available in Chennai, India?

Tags: mpmovieplayercontroller, iad

I am working on displaying an iAd advertisement before a video plays, but the ad is not playing and I receive the following error:

```
 Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=0 
 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (ADErrorDomain error 0.)"
```

There is no clear solution to me. So I have some doubt whether iAd is available in my region or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iAd is supported in India. You can see it included in the most recent list of [iAd supported countries](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203102).

Your issue may be that you've set your iAd Testing Fill Rate to 0% on your development device.

Go to Settings>Developer>Fill Rate> and set it to 100%.

Also, make sure you're giving your advertisement time to load before trying to present it. Check out my implementations of iAd's Pre-Roll Video Ads here: [Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32182076/2108547), [Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31908855/2108547).

Comment: Thank u Daniel,I used the code as you mentioned in above link (objective c) but Ad is not displaying and i am getting this Error only -> Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=0 
 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (ADErrorDomain error 0.)"

Comment: @Jiyas Did you check your fill rate settings and give your application enough time to load the advertisement? For example, launch the application, wait 30 seconds, attempt to present advertisement.