# Pre-Roll Video Ad with AVPlayerViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iad, avplayer

I'm having a problem with iAd's Pre-Roll Video Ad.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.ebookfrenzy.com/ios_book/movie/movie.mov"];
    player = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
    player.showsPlaybackControls = YES;
    AVPlayer *playerP = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:url];

    player.player = playerP;
    player.delegate = self;
}

- (IBAction)buttonClick:(id)sender {
    [self presentViewController:player animated:YES completion:^{
        [player playPrerollAdWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {

            if (error != nil) {
                NSLog(@"Error Message: %@", error);
            }
        }];
        NSLog(@"Completion");
    }];
}
```

I am getting the following error when running:

> Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)"

The iAd Pre-Roll Video Ad is not displayed. I followed this documentation:
[Monetizing your   iOS apps with iAd](https://developer.apple.com/iad/resources/Implementing-iAd-in-Your-iOS-Apps.PDF)

I also allowed `Arbitrary Loads` in my `info.plist`

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

Comment: iOS doesn't support http!!! You need to have https!!!! OR you need to allow http connections!!!! Read about ATS!!

Comment: I alowed connection in info.plist `<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/></dict>`

Comment: @Mr.T I'm pretty sure all of iAd's servers use `https`. Do you have a link you could provide stating that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `preparePrerollAds` in your `viewDidLoad` to download the advertisement before attempting to present it.

```
[AVPlayerViewController preparePrerollAds];
```

Check my example using a `MPMoviePlayerController` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31908855/2108547). It's the same approach.

Also, If you're testing on a development device go to Settings>Developer>Fill Rate> and make sure it is set to 100%.

Comment: Daniel. Thanks! More one question. How disable pre-roll video controls? Button Done for example!

Comment: @monteiro_luiz I'm not sure if that is possible/allowed by Apple. You should ask a new question pertaining to the removal of the *done* button.